# Sorting dates by semesters in R

Tags: r, sorting, time, tibble

I would like to sort (and rearrange) columns in a tibble object.  The table (let's call it `dataSet`) that I am working with looks like this:

| Fall 2019 | Fall 2020 | Spring 2019 | Spring 2020 | Spring 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | 32 | 43 | 25 |
| 15 | 84 | 94 | 64 | 65 |

I would like to have it sorted in the following order.

| Spring 2019 | Fall 2019 | Spring 2020 | Fall 2020 | Spring 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 1 | 43 | 36 | 25 |
| 94 | 15 | 64 | 84 | 65 |

Since the columns are *essentially* strings, I have tried using `str_sort(names(dataSet))`.  However, this returns the original column names as it *is* already sorted.  If I can get the column's name sorted, I know I can rearrange the columns in the tibble object.  I've worked with time objects before, but those are usually for formats like *mm/dd/yyyy*, but nothing in terms of semesters.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add a reproducible example? using dput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work for the data provided but the order of seasons can vary depending on what part of the world we are in.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(`Fall 2019` = c(1, 15), `Fall 2020` = c(36, 84), `Spring 2019` = c(32, 94), `Spring 2020` = c(43, 64), `Spring 2021` = c(25, 65))


names(df) %>% str_match('^(\\D+) (\\d+)') %>%
  as_tibble %>% 
  arrange(V3, desc(V2)) %>% `[`(, 1) %>% 
  pull %>% 
  {select_at(df, .)}
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   `Spring 2019` `Fall 2019` `Spring 2020` `Fall 2020` `Spring 2021`
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1            32           1            43          36            25
#> 2            94          15            64          84            65
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `relocate` here with the indices. You could also use the names:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  relocate(3,1,4,2,5)
```

```
  Spring2019 Fall2019 Spring2020 Fall2020 Spring2021
1         32        1         43       36         25
2         94       15         64       84         65
```